# Why does UITableViewCell backgroundView blur an image

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am subclassing a UITableViewCell and in the init function I am doing the following:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"packagelistcell_background.png"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 81)];
self.backgroundView = imageView;
[imageView release];
```

When that displays on the screen, the image appears slightly blurred.  For testing, I placed a straight UIImageView above the table view and the image looks perfect and crisp.  The table view is a grouped table view.  Do you know why it is blurring the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cell has been resized and so is the backgroundView.

Try

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try shifting the imageView by 0.5 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately @freytag's solution didn't work for me.

To solve this problem I had to add the UIImageView to a UIView container and set this last as background view of my Custom Cell instead of setting directly the UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"cellBackground.png"];
UIView *backgrContainer  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.backgroundView.frame];
[backgrContainer addSubview:imgView];
[self setBackgroundView:backgrContainer];// instead of  [self setBackgroundView:imgView];
[backgrContainer release];
[imgView release];
```

For some reason setting directly the UIImageView makes it blurry (even if no resize ocurrs). Setting autoresizingMask = None or contentMode <> ScaleToFill for the UIImageView did not fix my problem.

Also beware of the UITableView style, since using a Grouped Style will result in less width for the cell's background view, and this can also resize the image.

( Retina device/simulator doesn't seem to have this problems about blurry image in the cell backgroundVIew)